# How can I call a Javascript function from a website?

Tags: javascript, html, function, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a program that will be used by different users and they will individually change the content of the js file to match with their expectation.

On the web I found many tutorials on how to call JS function in unity WEBGL but the Js file was built with the unity project.

I wanted a way to call a JS function which is hosted by the website (incluing it in the index.html of unity WEBGL but without building it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is possible. But it is a bit of a hack.

a quick google search turned up [this article](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html), from the unity documentation
But it might not be clear how to do it. so here is an example:

## example:

Let us say you want to call a js function called `foo()`.

### .jslib

The first thing to do is create a file with a .jslib file extension in a folder named "Plugins".
this file tells unity that the function exists and is a just js

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
   foo_js: function () {
      foo()
   },
});
```

Here I declare a function called `foo_js` and tell unity that it exists.
This function consists of js, and in this case, all it does is call the js function `foo()`.

**Note**: the name `foo_js` is arbitrary, and it can be called anything, Including just `foo`. but it is the same name as you will be using in c#. so I would recommend making it clear that it is not a native c# function

### c#

now in a c# script, you start by declaring the function, which is done by  adding

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void foo_js();
```

to a class and add

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

to the top of the file

you can now call the function as `foo_js()` in your c# script

### after built

after you have built the unity project, you need to add a js script. To "index.html" that has a function called `foo()` for unity to call.

And it should work, for more detail read the article from the beginning.

## Edit:

Something I forgot to mention is that it is not going to work in the editor, as the js function is not defined, so you need to export the project and define the function on the website
it should be possible to detect that the game is running in the editor and use a default behaviour instead of the js function, but I am not sure how right now

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering to me, the fact is that the article that you gave me is the documentation of Unity and i already read it but i thought it was only used to put a js file in the build and use it. Thanks a lot, I will try this know !!!

Comment: It doesn't work :( it tells me "ReferenceError : foo() is not defined" :/

Comment: I made an edit for some clarity, and I also want to remind you that the process is a hack.